Compact operators vs Bounded operators between infinite dimensional spaces
Consider normed linear spaces $X, Y$ (not necessarily Banach), $T:X\to Y$ a linear map.
It is known that if either $\text{dim}\,X<\infty$ or $\text{dim}\,Y<\infty$ then the set $B(X,Y)$ of all bounded linear operators and the set $C(X,Y)$ of all compact linear operators are the same: $C(X,Y)=B(X,Y)$, and in general, it is not hard to see $C(X,Y)\subset B(X,Y)$ (these can be found in Kreyzig's book for example).
My question: when $\text{dim}\,X=\infty$ and $\text{dim}\,Y=\infty$, can one show that $C(X,Y)$ is strictly contained in $B(X,Y)$?
When $Y=X$, one can simply take the identity map $I_X:X\to X: x\mapsto x$ as an example. But I am struggling to find such an example in the general case.

The general case is, in fact, false. For example, if $X$ is a separable reflexive Banach space (say, $X = \ell^p$ for any $1 < p < \infty$) and $Y = \ell^1$, then all bounded linear operators $T: X \to Y$ are compact. Indeed, the closed unit ball $B_X$ of $X$ is compact metrizable under the weak topology, so it is sequentially compact. Hence, as any bounded operator is weak-weak continuous, $T(B_X)$ is weakly sequentially compact. But $\ell^1$ has Schur’s property - every weakly convergent sequence is convergent in norm. It is not hard to see that this implies a weakly sequentially compact subset of $\ell^1$ must be compact in the norm topology. Thus, $T(B_X)$ is compact in the norm topology, so $T$ is compact.

There is even a theorem (that should have a name which I do not recall right now) that, for $1\le p < q \le\infty$, every continuous linear operator $T:\ell^p\to\ell^p$ is compact.

@Jochen I think you mean every bounded operator $\ell^p \to \ell^q$ with $p>q$ is compact. This is Pitt's theorem
